# iOS - Use live camera output for SKVideoNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, avfoundation

Is it possible to use live camera output (like an AVCaptureSession) as input for an SKVideoNode? All the example and docs I've found only use prerecorded video, either through an AVPlayer or file URL.

I'm able to render the video in the background by making the scene transparent but I'd like the video to be part of the scene (for screenshoting and other manipulations that are better done within the SKScene)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? If so, how ?